# Calling Rails Helper from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, helper

I don't have much familiarity with Rails.

Is there a way to update/create Rails script from Javascript?

I am using a helper that edits images and creates a new image url. I have several images on the webpage, but each image has 3 URLs with different sized images to display based on screen size/orientation.

Instead of creating 3 divs/img tags for each image, and thus writing out the helper lines 3 times for each image, I'd like for Javascript to use media queries to call the helper and update the img srce accordingly.

I am well versed in JS and JQuery, but have hardly any experience with Rails.

I've added script to the html file:

```
<script>
    var test = <%= helper('https://url.com', :option1 =>1100, :option2 =>1300;) =%>

</script>
```

But this returns the console error: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`

EDIT:

Also, is it possible to add JS variables in the helper's parameters?

```
 <script>
    var jsVariable1 = 1100
    var test = <%= helper('https://url.com', :option1 =>JsVariable1, :option2 =>1300;) =%>

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your script to this.

`

```
   var test = <%= helper('https://url.com', :option1 =>1100, :option2 =>1300) =%>;

</script>`.
```

You need to change the location for ; As far as the update and creating are concerned. You need to use strong parameters for updating a hash. Next 
you need to pass the same arguments as for name , email, number you need to pass a hash as `{name: "aditya", email: "nitbaditya@gmail.com", number: "1"}`.

Comment: I added a semicolon at the end earlier and got the same error. I added it again with the numbers in quotes and still get the error.

This is what I have now:

-

```var test = <%= helper('https://url.com', option1:"1100", option2:"1300") =%>;```

Comment: It seems like the problem is the colon in the url